# Is a function continuous iff its restriction to each element of an open cover is continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $(X;T_1)$ and $(Y;T_2)$ be topological spaces and let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty subsets
of $X$ with $A\cup B= X$
Suppose $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a function. Then prove or disprove:

(a) if $f_A$ and $f_B$ are continuous, then $f$ is continuous, where $f_A$ and $f_B$ are restrictions of $f$ to $A$ and $B$ respectively

(b) if $f_A$ and $f_B$ are continuous and the intersection of boundary of $A$ and boundary of $B$ is empty then $f$ is continuous.

The answer in this post was quite helpful: [A function on $X$ is continuous iff its restriction to each element of an open cover is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359997/a-function-on-x-is-continuous-iff-its-restriction-to-each-element-of-an-open-c)

Q-1 In my question it's not given that $A$ and $B$ are open. So (a) is false. Can someone give a counterexample for this? How to disprove it?

Q-2 I can't seem to understand part (b). The condition that the intersection of boundary of $A$ and boundary of $B$ is empty, is it a substitute for $A$ and $B$ being open? This doesn't make sense to me. I can't relate this extra condition to the continuity of $f$.

Comment: For (a), think about making $A$ finite, or even just one point, and say $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

For (a), consider the step function $f: [0, 2] \to [0, 1]$, given by
$$
f(x) = \left\{
\begin{align}
0, & x < 1 \\
1, & x \ge 1,
\end{align}
\right. 
$$
with $A = [0, 1)$ and $B = [1, 2]$.

The restrictions $f|_A$ and $f|_B$ are constant, hence continuous, functions, while $f$ certainly is not.  Notice that $\partial A \cap \partial B \ne \varnothing$.

Comment: any pointers for (b) ?